# Modify data structure of CarrierWave image uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rubygems, carrierwave

I'm using the ruby gem CarrierWave to handle images on my rails app, which is a mobile backend API. Is there a way to store the image url and thumb url directly on the parent object?

This is the default behavior, shown in the post object's json. Notice the nested JSON:

```
{
created_at: "2012-11-17T18:24:04Z",
description: "this is the content",
id: 6,
user_id: 1,
picture: {
url: "/uploads/entry/picture/6/wtf_llama.jpeg",
  thumb: {
    url: "/uploads/entry/picture/6/thumb_wtf_llama.jpeg"
    }
  },
updated_at: "2012-11-26T08:16:43Z"
}
```

What I'd like to see:

```
{
created_at: "2012-11-17T18:24:04Z",
description: "this is the content",
id: 6,
user_id: 1,
picture_url = "/uploads/entry/picture/6/wtf_llama.jpeg",
thumb_url = "/uploads/entry/picture/6/thumb_wtf_llama.jpeg"
updated_at: "2012-11-26T08:16:43Z"
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Kyle, did you ever figure this out? I've run into the same issue, myself, and would like to have a flatter data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why storing those paths in models?  Improve response (view or controller), not persistence layer (model).  I believe it's easiest to achieve with [as_json](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json).  Either add `picture_url` methods to model or merge additional entries to your final hash.

Comment: Are you familiar with CarrierWave? From all I've seen this is the de facto way to handle images in a Rails application. But yes, what I'm essentially asking is how that can be done.

Comment: Carrierwave stores path to default version of file (or just file name, don't remember) and generate paths to other version using convenient standards (like prepending name with "thumb_").  I wouldn't change that, although it's possible with some patching.  Craft the response in controller (or view), storage is fine.  And carrierwave is about storing, it's strictly model-related, not controller-related nor view-related.

Comment: I meant sth like: `Picture.as_json(only: [:id, :user_id, :picture_url, :thumb_url])` and `def picture_url ; picture.url ; end`.  Possibly you could use delegations instead of method definition.